# При работе с массивом получаю ошибку ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, массивы

Новичок в Java, да и в программировании в целом. Скорей всего ошибка в цикле, но где точно я так и не понял. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Задача:

> Написать код, который переворачивает массив: {1,2,3,7} >
>   {7,3,2,1}

Исполнение:

```
package Homework;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x[]= new int[]{1,2,3,7};
    for (int i = 0; i <= (x.length/2-1); i++) {
        int j;
        j = x[i];
        x[i]=x[x.length-i];
        x[x.length-i]=j;            
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
  }
}
```

То, что выводит консоль после компиляции:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
at Homework.Main.main(Main.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Пусть `i` равно нулю. К какому элементу массива обращается это выражение `x[x.length-i]`?

Comment: Спасибо за то что указали на мою невнимательность. В этом и заключалась ошибка кода. Задача решена :) Решение: x[x.length-i-1]

Comment: @PetSerAl средний элемент остается на месте. можно его не трогать

Comment: @Icecream Если вы получили решение, которое вам помогло, отметьте соответствующий ответ верным. [Что делать когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Saidolim Не за средний элемент я беспокоился. Из-за `-1` в условии цикла, мне показалось, что соседние к среднему элементы не переставляются.

Comment: Поскольку длина массива не меняется, достаточно вычислить её однажды.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length/2; i++) {
    int j;
    j = x[i];
    x[i] = x[x.length - i - 1];
    x[x.length - i - 1] = j;
}
```

тут не нужни минусовать каждый раз, сделайте не равно

```
i < x.length/2
```

исправте индексы

```
x[i] = x[x.length - i - 1];
x[x.length - i - 1] = j;
```

Из комментариев

> P.S. Я бы советовал Вам проверить работы алгоритма на массивах нечётной длинны  – *PetSerAl*

Так как при нечетной длине элемент по середине остается на месте, можно его не трогать

Answer (score 3):

Массив идет от 0 до 3.
Вы же здесь обращаетесь в первой итерации к 4ой ячейке.

```
x[i]=x[x.length-i];
x[x.length-i]=j;
```

Надо исправить на:

```
x[i]=x[x.length-i-1];
x[x.length-i-1]=j;
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы получаете ошибку *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4* - это значит, что у вас выход за пределы массива, значение индекса равно 4 (при том что в массиве есть только индексы [0-3] - первый индекс имеет значение 0), то есть не существует элемента массива с таким индексом, к которому вы пытаетесь обратиться.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x[] = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 7};
for (int i = 0; i <= (x.length / 2 - 1); i++) {
    int j;
    j = x[i];
    x[i] = x[x.length - i - 1];
    x[x.length - i - 1] = j;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```